# How can I avoid surrounding underscores to be converted in Trello card descriptions?

Tags: trello

When I am trying to add for example WS_EX_APPWINDOW as a text in a Trello card description it'll be converted to WS*EX*APPWINDOW.

Am I assuming correct, that surrounding underscores are used for italic style?

How can I achieve to display WS_EX_APPWINDOW without conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trello accept Markdown syntax in card descriptions.
When you surround a word with underscores it will be printed in *italic*

However you can use underscores escaping them, e.g.

```
WS\\_EX\\_APPWINDOW
```

will be printed as

```
WS_EX_APPWINDOW
```

If you wan to know more on markdown syntax please refer to the [official documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

Comment: Ah nice. Haven't paid much attention to markdown so far. But since it is also used on Stack Exchange I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Code blocks may also be helpful.

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to markdown, I ended up using backtick quotes (`) to indicate the mentioned `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` example as code within the text. Within the code span the underscore conversion is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

### As at June 2022

---

```
meta\_data\__c
```

Prints as

meta_data__c

---

```
meta_data\__c
```

prints as

meta_data__c

---

```
`meta_data__c`
```

is the nicest,
it puts it in a code block
a bit like this:

> `meta_data__c`

---

**INCORRECT WAY:**

```
meta_data\_\_c
```

prints as

meta_data|_c

---